# How can a celery worker consume a task from RabbitMQ but be unable to send one?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

We use Django, Celery and RabbitMQ to handle various automated workers. To monitor all of this, we have an rabbit queue for analytics and logging. This means that every automated task should be able to send tasks to the analytics queue. 
We are running the workers with "./manage.py celery worker" and our broker connection works fine. The worker can pick up the required task and execute it perfectly fine but during execution when it comes to

```
log_event.delay()
```

suddenly it cannot connect. Through digging through the amqp library and some pdb.set_trace() we found that during task execution, it's attempting to connect to localhost instead of to our rabbitmq server. 
Here are the relevant broker settings:

local_settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost:5672/'
```

celeryconfig.py

```
import os
from kombu import Queue
from celery import Celery
from . import local_settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sample.settings.production')
app = Celery('api')

BROKER_URL = getattr(local_settings, 'BROKER_URL', 'amqp://guest@broker/')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', routing_key='default'),
    Queue('queue1', routing_key='queue1'),
    Queue('queue2', routing_key='queue2'),
    Queue('queue3', routing_key='queue3'),
    Queue('queue4', routing_key='queue4'),
)

CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {
    'appname.tasks.queue1_task': {'rate_limit': '200/m'},
    'appname.tasks.queue2_task': {'rate_limit': '200/m'},
    'appname.tasks.queue3_task': {'rate_limit': '200/m'},
    'appname.tasks.queue4_task': {'rate_limit': '200/m'},
}

CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 10

CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'tasks'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'


CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'appname.tasks.queue1': {
        'queue': 'queue1',
        'routing_key': 'queue1',
    },
    'appname.tasks.queue2': {
        'queue': 'queue2',
        'routing_key': 'queue2',
    },
    'appname.tasks.queue3': {
        'queue': 'queue3',
        'routing_key': 'queue3',
    },
    'appname.tasks.queue4': {
        'queue': 'queue4',
        'routing_key': 'queue4',
    },
}

CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
```

tasks.py

```
from celery.task import task #We also tried shared_task, no success
@task(time_limit=120, queue="queue1")
def log_action_to_es(cls, analytic_dict):
    pass # Never gets this far
```

Comment: Where is log_event.delay()? Could you show the call stack. And you could try to use app.task instead using task to decorate log_action_to_es, refer to the demo in http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#using-celery-in-your-application